# Unable to align UI items properly

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Please have a look at the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/save_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/save_to" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/save_location_radio_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/save_txt"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/save_txt">

        <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/save_selection_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_sd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="SD" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Phone" />
    </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>





    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/save_name_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/save_txt"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/save_name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/save_name_edt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/save_txt"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/save_name_txt"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/save_name_txt"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:ems="8" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_voice_note_button"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/save_txt"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/save_name_edt"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/save_name_edt"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This generates the following

[image]

There are 2 issues.

1. As you can see, the `RadioButton`s are not aligned to the right of 'Save To: ' `TextView`
2. This is actually a `Dialog` and when I open this window, the height of the window is not enough. Please refer to the image, it displays only 90% of the `EditText` and `Button`.

I have done my best to correct this but still no good. What have I done wrong?

Comment: in your linear layout remove these lines  android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/save_txt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix problem with dialog height, change `android:layout_height` of your main RelativeLayout to `wrap_content`.

To align radio buttons with TextView, change `@+id/save_txt` and `@+id/save_location_radio_layout` to:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/save_txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/save_to" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/save_location_radio_layout"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/save_location_radio_layout"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/save_location_radio_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/save_txt"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

place your Save To: text view also in first linear layout and give padding between textview and radio group..

Answer (score 0):

```
try this out

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:id="@+id/headertop"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/save_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="save_to" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/save_location_radio_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/save_txt"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/save_selection_group"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_sd"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="SD" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_phone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Phone" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/save_name_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headertop"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="save_name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/save_name_edt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/save_name_txt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headertop"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/save_name_txt"
        android:ems="8"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_voice_note_button"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/save_name_edt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headertop"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/save_name_edt"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above comments.

You can't be sure that all elemnts fit in dialog because it's size depends on screen dimensions. You should optimzie UI to fit well on most part of screens and wrap ScrollView around RelativeLayout. It will be new root element.